# Будет ли прямое обращение к полям enum нарушением инкапсуляции?

Tags: java, ооп

Есть `enum`

```
public enum HQuery {
    GET_USER_BY_LOG_PASS("select u from User u where u.login = :login and u.password = :password");
    public String value;

    HQuery(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Если я буду обращеться к значению `value` таким образом: `GET_USER_BY_LOG_PASS.value` это будет нарушением принципа инкапсуляции? Или на `enum` это правило не распространяется так жестко как на классы?

Comment: `enum` - это костыль и к ООП никак не относится. не стоит его использовать так же как используют объекты. инкапсуляция это не про доступ к полям, а про знание реализации. пользователь объекта не должен знать о том как этот объект внутри устроен. он должен знать интерфейс и все.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman "инкапсуляция это не про доступ к полям, а про знание реализации" а доступ к полям к знаниям реализации не относится?

Comment: если вы не имеете доступ к полям, но используете знание реализации, то принцип инкапсуляции будет нарушен. а если у вас есть несколько геттеров, которые являются частью интерфейса, то это может и не быть нарушением принципа. на мой взгляд представленный `enum` - это плохой дизайн и я бы не стал такое делать.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman что конкретно вы понимаете под знанием реализаии? Я так и не понял из ваших слов прямой доступ к полям к реализации относится или нет?